# Solving lim(x^x) when x approaches minus infinity

Tags: limits, limsup-and-liminf, limits-without-lhopital

so I have an issue and I have to solve this limit $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}x^x$$ so I worked on it and tried to solve it.

My attempt:

Let there be a second variable $y=-x$.So we have this $$\lim_{x \to -\infty}y=\lim_{x \to -\infty}-x=+\infty$$ So when $$ x \to -\infty \Rightarrow y \to +\infty$$Now working with the actual limit$$\lim_{x \to -\infty}x^x=\lim_{x \to -\infty}\frac{-1}{-x^{-x}}$$ but $$-x=y$$ so $$\lim_{x \to -\infty}x^x=\lim_{y \to +\infty}\frac{-1}{y^y}=0$$ because $$\lim_{x\to +\infty}x^x=+\infty$$

Can I do all these or not?? Thanks for your time

Comment: What is $x^x$ when $x<0$? You seem to think that this is $-1/|x|^{|x|}$, why?

Comment: isnt x^x well defined when x is near -infinity?

Comment: Is it? What is $(-42.5)^{-42.5}$ then?

Comment: How would you define $(-\pi )^{-\pi}$? The domain of $x^x$ is $x > 0$.

Comment: @Crostul But $-\pi$ is not near enough to $-\infty$, I guess... :-)

Comment: Certainly not. Generally speaking, $x^y$ is defined as $\;\mathrm e^{y\ln x}$. Draw the conclusion.

Comment: isnt it $-1/(42.5)^(42.5)$... and so as $π $

Comment: Wait... In general, one considers that $a^{-b}=1/a^b$, right? Hence, if $(-42.5)^{-42.5}=-1/42.5^{42.5}$, that means that $(-42.5)^{42.5}=-42.5^{42.5}$, right? Why? ...You see, this is just absurd and there is no canonical definition of $x^y$ when $x<0$.

Comment: Right !!! thanks alot ... so there ia no solution to this , because my function is not well defined

Comment: Everything you did seems right to me. In responce to @Did, When $x<0$, $x^y=(i\sqrt{-x})^{2y}=(\cos(\pi y) + i\sin(\pi y))\cdot(-x)^y$ (assuming $x$ and $y$ are real). Wouldn't that be a canonical definition? EDIT: Also, if you put $x^x$ into wolfram alpha, it seems to approach zero as x approaches negative infinity.

Comment: @Polygon Nope. Best to avoid this altogether unless one wants to fall into elementary traps such as $x_1^yx_2^y\ne(x_1x_2)^y$. (And I would recommend avoiding to confirm dubious statements to the OP unless one is quite sure to master the subject...)

Comment: @AntonisSk Exactly. (What is your source for this?)

Comment: well a not reliable enough ... a friend

Comment: @AntonisSk Hm, then I hope we leave you and your friend more informed.  :)

Comment: you did ... and thanks again !! :D

Answer (score 1):

The short version is you've made a grouping error.  It's correct to say $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}x^x = \lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{-1}{-(x^{-x})}$$ but you have to remember that the minus sign in the denominator is *outside* the exponent.  You implicitly pull it inside when you switch in $y$, and that's where you went wrong.  A substitution you *can* make, however, is $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}x^x = \lim_{y\to+\infty}(-y)^{-y} = \lim_{y\to+\infty}e^{-y\ln(-y)}$$  The natural log of a negative number is a multivalued function, but in this case, you'll see that any choice gives the same answer, so for now we'll write $$\lim_{y\to+\infty}e^{-y(\ln y + k\pi i)}$$ where $k$ is an arbitrary odd integer.  (I'm assuming you're familiar with the identity $e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x$; if not, well, there it is.)  So you end up with $$\lim_{y\to+\infty}e^{-y\ln y }e^{-k\pi iy} = \lim_{y\to+\infty}\frac{e^{-k\pi iy}}{y^y}$$  The denominator obviously blows up, whereas the numerator stays on the unit circle, so the limit is zero.